# How to create .htaccess in my Live server /home/username/public_html/

Tags: php

How to create .htaccess in home/username/public_html/  my Live Server .

it's possible to create .htaccess file my Live Server

Comment: Yes, just make the text file then rename it

Comment: you can create `.htaccess` file from `cmd` prompt window, go to dir path and use `edit .htaccess` and save file

Answer (score 0):

To create a .htaccess file you simply do the following:

1. Create a text file and place HTACCESS content
2. Save file
3. Rename file to .htaccess
4. Sucess you have now created a .htaccess file!

if your on windows make sure you click save as then where it says .txt change that to any and save the file as .htaccess

Comment: Also the tag php does not fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you can't simply just create a file and rename it.

> [image]

First, open notepad (winkey + r -> notepad -> OK), then go to File -> Save As...

> [image]

Make sure to switch the `Save as Type` to `All Files (*.*)`, and for your filename type `.htaccess`.

---

If you're on Linux (as /home/ would indicate), this process is much easier:

Just enter `cat > /home/username/public_html/.htaccess` and enter your content.

Comment: Ahh. Yes that is true.

Answer (score 0):

- Create *htaccess.txt*
- Open file and go to *file* -> *save as* ->

  - file name= *.htaccess*
  - file save as type = *all files (".")*
  - Encoding = *UTF-8*

Comment: Try to explain more the answer .